# How to convert a frequency table into a vector of values?

Tags: r, dataset, excel

Using R or Excel, what is the easiest way to convert a frequency table into a  vector of values?

E.g., How would you convert the following frequency table

```
Value   Frequency
  1.      2
  2.      1
  3.      4
  4.      2
  5.      1
```

into the following vector?

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In R, you can do it using the `rep`command:

```
tab <- data.frame(value=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), freq=c(2, 1, 4, 2, 1))
vec <- rep(tab$value, tab$freq)
```

This gives following result:

```
> tab
  value freq
1     1    2
2     2    1
3     3    4
4     4    2
5     5    1

> vec
 [1] 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 5
```

For details, see the help file for the `rep`command by typing `?rep`.

Comment: Or, given a simple frequency table for `vec <- sample(1:5, 20, TRUE)` created by `table()`: `rep(names(table(vec)), table(vec))`. The result then needs to be converted with `as.numeric()` if the categories are actual numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously in R it's simpler.

In Excel I would use a helper column (if the **value** is in A1):

```
  value freq help
1     1    2  =REPT(A2 & ", ",B2)
2     2    1  =C1 & REPT(A3 & ", ",B3)
3     3    4  (drag or copy from upper cell)
4     4    2  (drag or copy from upper cell)
5     5    1  (drag or copy from upper cell)
              =LEFT(C6, LEN(C6)-1)
```

In C7 you have your result